# android exoplayer custom datasource

Tags: android, datasource, exoplayer

I am developing a custom `DataSource` object to use in `ExoPlayer`.

I am having problems understanding how to connect it to `Samplesource` objects so that data requests from underlying `Exoplayer` components happen via my `DataSource` object.

Has anybody got this working?

Appreciate any comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SampleSource (or ChunkSource) takes the upstream DataSource object in its constructor - that is how you connect a DataSource to SampleSource (or ChunkSource)

Let me take an example of HLS to illustrate how to inject your custom DataSource to SampleSource.

In  https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/HlsRendererBuilder.java

Existing Code

```
DataSource dataSource = new UriDataSource(userAgent, bandwidthMeter);
HlsChunkSource chunkSource = new HlsChunkSource(dataSource, url, manifest, bandwidthMeter, null,
    HlsChunkSource.ADAPTIVE_MODE_SPLICE);
HlsSampleSource sampleSource = new HlsSampleSource(chunkSource, true, 3);
```

Let's assume you implement a CustomDataSource class. New code will look like this

```
CustomDataSource dataSource = new CustomDataSource(<your arguments here>);
HlsChunkSource chunkSource = new HlsChunkSource(dataSource, url, manifest, bandwidthMeter, null,
    HlsChunkSource.ADAPTIVE_MODE_SPLICE);
HlsSampleSource sampleSource = new HlsSampleSource(chunkSource, true, 3);
```

Comment: There's no explanation on the internet on how to use data sources with ExoPlayer. Here's the closest thing I found: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exoplayer-in-android-with-example/